# Turn a string formatted as an array into an array using javascript/ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to turn a string like:

```
"[["firstVal","secondVal"],["firstVal","secondVal"]]"
```

Into a javascript array (It is a 2D array)

Is there a way that I can do this using javascript or jQuery?

Many Thanks!

Comment: you could also use eval, even though you shouldn't. https://jsfiddle.net/nLzkne3r/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse` to achieve what you require:

```js
var str = '[["firstVal","secondVal"],["firstVal","secondVal"]]';
var arr = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(arr);
```

Note that I had to amend the outer quotes to `'` as your example string is malformed.

Comment: Thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

Use [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method to do that :

```
JSON.parse('[["firstVal","secondVal"],["firstVal","secondVal"]]');
```